# Key point vector not working in ORB implementation of opencv.js

Tags: javascript, opencv, web, feature-detection, orb

i was trying to print the keypoints in the orb feature matching but it was not showing the keypoints.

here is my code

```
var kp1 = new cv.KeyPointVector();                                                                   --------here is the keypoint vector
// find the keypoints with ORB
orb.detect(orig, kp1, noArray1);
// compute the descriptors with ORB

var das=new cv.Mat();   
orb.compute(orig, kp1, das);
```

In this keypoint vector should contain all the key feature points and i want to console.log() all the keypoints, could you please help me in finding the solution

when I tried to access the points then keypoints vector didn't have the point property which is available otherwise in python

Comment: Did you instantiated the orb detector object before? If not you need to do it, please share your complete code for looking for replication

Comment: Also please use kp1(0) on console and post the results, that should give you the first keypoint's information